# cordova camera crash on android 6

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 1 app that uses `cordova-camera-plugin`. Overall, it works well, but I'm running into issues with the app crashing on Android 5.x/6.x. Oddly, this doesn't happen on all devices running these versions.

Here's the output of `ionic info`:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v8.9.4
    npm        : 5.6.0
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

For some reason, the only permission that's added to `AndroidManifest.xml` is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, so I went ahead and manually added `CAMERA` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Here's the full file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="6032" android:versionName="1.6.0" package="com.scoutforpets.staff" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" />
        <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.SyncService" android:process=":sync">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.AuthenticatorService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <provider android:authorities="@string/content_authority" android:exported="false" android:name="com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.DummyContentProvider" android:syncable="true" />
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.marianhello.bgloc.BootCompletedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver" />
        <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.scoutforpets.staff" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity" />
        <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />
        <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.scoutforpets.staff.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.scoutforpets.staff.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Here's my `config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget android-versionCode="6033" id="com.scoutforpets.staff" ios-CFBundleVersion="574" version="1.6.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Scout</name>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="*://maps.apple.com/*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*://maps.apple.com/*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="http://10.69.0.93:8100"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="true"/>
    <hook src="scripts/incrementBuildNum.js" type="before_build"/>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Keyboard">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard"/>
    </feature>
    <platform name="ios">
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="*"/>
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="9.0"/>
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57"/>
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114"/>
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40"/>
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80"/>
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120"/>
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50"/>
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100"/>
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60"/>
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180"/>
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144"/>
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76"/>
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152"/>
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167"/>
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29"/>
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58"/>
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87"/>
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750"/>
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242"/>
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536"/>
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768"/>
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320"/>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>This app needs camera access to take pictures.</string>
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <access origin="*"/>
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="geo:*"/>
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="120000"/>
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0"/>
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="git+https://github.com/amritk/cordova-plugin-firebase.git"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="^2.3.3">
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account"/>
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME"/>
        <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app always requires location tracking"/>
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="+"/>
        <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon"/>
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon"/>
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name"/>
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name"/>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3"/>
    <plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="^0.8.5"/>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.2.5"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-hockeyapp" spec="^5.1.2"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" "/>
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" "/>
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Whenever I load this app up on an LG G4, G5 or MotoX running Android 5.x/6.x and click the camera button, I'm prompted to:

- Allow Scout to take pictures and record video?
- Allow Scout to access photos, media, and files on your device?

I accept both and am able to take a picture. Once I've hit "OK" on the camera interface, the app crashes and I get the message "Unfortunately, Scout has stopped."

Looking at the adb logs, I see the following right after that happens:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=33, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.scoutforpets.staff/com.scoutforpets.staff.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/464 from pid=30553, uid=10191 
requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission() 

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/464 from pid=30553, uid=10191 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

As you can see from above, I've explicitly added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

As I mentioned earlier, this doesn't happen on all devices running those versions of Android. For example, a Galaxy S7 running 6.0.1 works just fine.

I'd really appreciate any help as this is absolutely killing me right now!

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to manually request for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission using this plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was related to an external plugin modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` and limiting the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to SDK Level 18 and below.

For anyone who runs into a similar problem, this was caused by the HockeyApp plugin.

Here's the related issue: https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Cordova/issues/100